# Trabalhando com dicionário em python

Tags: python, string, dicionário

Estou tentando resolver uma questão no URI, vou colocar a descrição da questão, e o link, seja como vocês preferirem.

Link: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1215

*Andy de apenas 8 anos tem um sonho - ele deseja criar o seu próprio dicionário. Isto não é uma tarefa fácil para ele, pois conhece poucas palavras. Bem, ao invés de pensar nas palavras que sabe, ele teve uma idéia brilhante. A partir do seu livro de histórias favorito, ele vai criar um dicionário com todas as palavras distintas que existem nele. Ordenando estas palavras em ordem alfabética, o trabalho estará feito. É claro, isso é uma tarefa que toma um certo tempo e portanto, a ajuda de um programador de computador como você é muito bemvinda.*

*Você foi convidado a escrever um programa que liste todas as diferentes palavras que existem em um texto. Neste caso, uma palavra é definida como uma sequência de letras, maiúsculas ou minúsculas. Palavras com apenas uma letra também deverão ser consideradas. Portanto, seu programa deverá ser "CaSe InSeNsItIvE". Por exemplo, palavras como "Apple", "apple" ou "APPLE" deverão ser consideradas como a mesma palavra.*

**Entrada**

*A entrada contém no máximo 10000 linhas de texto, cada uma delas com no máximo 200 caracteres. O fim de entrada é determinado pelo EOF.*

**Saída**

*Você deve imprimir uma lista de diferentes palavras que aparecem no texto, uma palavra por linha. Todas as palavras devem ser impressas com letras minúsculas, em ordem alfabética. Deverá haver no máximo 5000 palavras distintas.*

Exemplo de entrada:

```
Ex(*$a#.mpl.e:

Adventures in Disneyland

Two blondes were going to Disneyland when they came to a fork in the road. The sign read: "Disneyland LEFT."

So they went home.
```

Saída deste exemplo:

```
a
adventures
blondes
came
disneyland
e
ex
fork
going
home
in
left
mpl
read
road
sign
so
the
they
to
two
went
were
when
```

Isso é o que eu tenho até agora:

```py
#Recebo a entrada, e já a converto para minúsculo
entrada = input()
entrada = entrada.lower()

#Tento remover todos os caracteres que não sejam letras. Aí está o PRINCIPAL erro do meu código, pois desta forma, sei que não consigo remover todos os caracteres desejados da string
S = entrada
for x in '0123456789+-*/[]{}().,?":~´`ªº!@#$%¨&_':
    S = S.replace(x, ' ')

#Armazeno cada "palavra" na lista, separando pelo o espaço vazio (' '), e ordeno a lista
L = S.split(' ')
L = sorted(set(L))

#Removo índices que estão vazios ('')
i = 0
while i < len(L):
    if L[i] == '':
        L.pop(i)
    i += 1

#Exibo o conteúdo de cada índice da lista, um por linha
j = 0
while j < len(L):
    print(L[j])
    j += 1
```

Acredito que o erro possa se resolver nesta parte do segundo comentário.

Comment: Cadê o erro? ...

Comment: Acho que o problema do seu programa é que ele não lê o input direito, precisa fazer um tratamento de EOF, mas não faço ideia de como fazer isso. Modifique sua pergunta para algo como: "o que é EOF em python?" ou "como ler EOF de um input em pyhton". No mais seu programa parece funcionar, eu só trocaria essa gambiarra do primeiro for pela função `isalpha()` do python, que retorna `true` caso a string tenha somente caracteres alfabétricos e `false` em caso contrário

Comment: Macho, era desse ```isalpha()``` que eu precisava, eu só achava resolução com o que remove se é numérico, acho que isso vai resolver meu problema

Answer (score 0):

Eu encontrei a função que verifica se o caractere é ou não é string, então utilizei o `isalpha()`, a minha saída ficou idêntica a saída exigida do URI, porém a questão continua com **Wrong answer (100%)**:

```py
entrada = input()
entrada = entrada.lower()

S = entrada
for x in S:
    if not(x.isalpha()):
        S = S.replace(x, ' ')

L = S.split(' ')
L = sorted(set(L))

i = 0
while i < len(L):
    if L[i] == '':
        L.pop(i)
    i += 1

j = 0
while j < len(L):
    print(L[j])
    j += 1
```

Minha saída utilizando o mesmo exelplo de entrada do URI:

```
a
adventures
blondes
came
disneyland
e
ex
fork
going
home
in
left
mpl
read
road
sign
so
the
they
to
two
went
were
when
```

Como vocês podem ver, minha saída está idêntica a do URI.

Comment: Davi Monteiro, eu acho que a entrada deve ser feita em de laço de repetição só parando quando encontrar `EOF`.